# What are so special in CLR Managed Exceptions Handling

Tags: c#, clr

This is theoretical Q. I'm the beginner in c# and just try to understand the key concepts and advantaged of managed programming languages.

The main key features of CLR (from many sources of CLR definitions) are:

A. Managing memory and garbage collector

B. Managing exceptions

C. Other stuff like type safety, security and thread management

When I fully understand the advantage of "managing memory" (it is really free the programmer from the all low level stuff of managing memory allocation/deallocation), I don't understand this feature of "managed exceptions handling".

Q: In other words, if C++ language (Non-managed language) support the "try, throw, and catch" exception handling model, **what is so special/beneficial/new in CLR "managed exceptions handling" model, what make the life of programmer more easy?** (relative to non-managed languages)

Thanks.

Comment: Great question, and I'd love to see someone smarter than me answer, but offhand, *managed exceptions carry the stack trace information*, even accounting for function inlining, while unmanaged exceptions do not. This, to me, is the biggest and most important difference.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference with C++.  Stack traces are a lot easier to come by, but it isn't impossible in C++ with sufficient effort.  That it is not easy in C++ has a lot to do with the fact that the language standard is created by an industry group with competing interests.  Such a standard has to make everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: "from many sources of CLR definitions" - out of curiosity, can you list some of these sources?

Comment: @Christian.K, sure. Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime. The CLR provides additional services including memory management, type safety, exception handling, garbage collection, security and thread management.